# Openlayers - Projection issues when getting latitude/longitude from a point

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I'm trying to get the latitude/longitude from a draggable marker with Openlayers and OSM but I can't find the good settings for the projection conversion, what I am doing wrong ?

Here is the code: http://pastie.org/2300321 (see addMarker l140 & updateTargets l153) & and a little [demo test](http://labs.julien-guigner.name/openlayers/).

If you submit an address, then drag the marker, the longitude and latitude are wrong. I tested a few different projections but I'm not sure what I've to use…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is inside `updateTargets` method:

```
var point = this.feature.geometry;
var pixel = new OpenLayers.Pixel(point.x, point.y);
var coord = this.map.getLonLatFromPixel(pixel).transform(
   new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
   new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
);
```

this.feature.geometry is already specified in lon/lat coordinates, not in pixels. So I suggest that you skip second line and do the conversion from OpenStreetMap projection to lon/lat directly on geometry object:

```
var coord = this.feature.geometry.transform(
   new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
   new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
);
```

Comment: Yes, it works :) I had to re-transform the projection after I get the coord to be able to re-drag the marker but it's good now, many thanks ;)